# org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Duplicate field state in record record_2: state type:UNION pos:4 and state type:UNION pos:1

Tags: hive, hdfs, avro

I am posting a question for the first time. I am trying to create a table by joining two existing tables among which one of my columns is a Collection of Structures. I am doing it on Hive. I want to store the table in AVRO format.

The Query that I am using to create the table is:

```
    create table emp_dtls_2_avro stored as AVRO as 
select
   'a.pk_dept' ,
   'a.dept_id',
   'a.dept_name',
   Collect_list(Named_struct ("emp_fname", b.emp_fname, "emp_lname", b.emp_lname, "emp_id", b.emp_id, "emp_ssn", b.emp_ssn, "emp_title", b.emp_title, "emp_accnt_dts", b.acc_loc_dts_arr, "emp_add_dtls", b.emp_add_arr)) as emp_dtls 
from
   dept a 
   inner join
      emp_dtls_1 b 
      on 'a.pk_dept' = 'b.fk_dept' 
group by
   'a.pk_dept',
   'a.dept_id',
   'a.dept_name';
```

I am facing an error over which I cannot understand and resolve. Any help will be appreciated:

```
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Duplicate field state in record record_2: state type:UNION pos:4 and state type:UNION pos:1.
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but, most likely: `on a.pk_dept = 'b.fk_dept'` should be: `on a.pk_dept = b.fk_dept` (the single quotes should not be there). Same in the `select` and `group by` clauses.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response ... If I remove all the single quotes I receive a new error - "SemanticException org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal character in: a.pk_dept". The single quotes removed this error but brought the above error which now I can't resolve.

Comment: I added the one single quote that I missed - on 'a.pk_dept' = 'b.fk_dept'

Comment: when you run the select query and see result, what does it show? Can you pls post sample pic? Trying to understand if columns generated by `select` has any duplicates or not. Also if you dont have any keywords, you dont need to enclose columns.